# Boost at not returning a type

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I have the following code that is failing to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/mpl/set.hpp"
#include "boost/mpl/at.hpp"
#include "boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp"

struct TypeSet {

    typedef boost::mpl::set<int, float> typeset;

    template<typename T>
    static bool hasType()
    {
        using namespace boost;
        using namespace boost::mpl;
        return is_same< at< typeset, T >::type, T >::value; // <-- ERROR IS HERE
    }  
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bool hasInt = TypeSet::hasType<int>();
    std::cout << (hasInt ? "set contains int" : "set does not contain int") << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

The code is being compiled with the Apple LLVM clang 4.1 compiler and boost 1.5.2 and the error is "Template argument for type parameter must be a type" - basically the compiler is complaining that `boost::mpl::at` is not returning a type. The offending code is taken pretty much verbatim from the boost documentation so I'm at a loss as to what's wrong with this (and as far as I can tell `boost::mpl::at` does return a type).

Comment: Works fine on MSVC++... I guess the docs code wasn't tested on all platforms.

Comment: @user673679 that is probably because MSVC++ is not standard compliant in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
typename at< typeset, T >::type
```

since it depends on template parameter `T`. So you have to tell the compiler that `type` is a type in this context.